# How do I set up a Camel route between two CXF endpoints where the SOAP faults are transferred correctly?

Tags: cxf, apache-camel

I set up a route between two CXF endpoints up like this:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="monitoringService"
  address="${esb.monitoring-service.ep.address}" serviceName="s:monitoring-service"
  endpointName="s:portSOAP" wsdlURL="classpath:/webservices/monitoring-service.wsdl"
  xmlns:s="http://xyz/monitoring/"
/>

<endpoint
  id="originMonitoringService"
  uri="${origin.monitoring-service.ep.address}" />

<route>
  <from uri="cxf:bean:monitoringService?dataFormat=MESSAGE" />
  <to ref="originMonitoringService" />
</route>
```

However when there are SOAP faults happening at the 'originMonitoringService' then they seem not to be forwarded to the endpoint published by Camel and as such do not reach the client that is connecting to it.

How am I supposed to declare this connection?

(Just FYI: ${xx}-style variable are properly replaced with values like http://somehost/someservice at runtime.)

Answer (score 1):

This issue should be fixed by [CAMEL-4570](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-4570)